# The Code is not generating a file for cookie in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html and Javascript code which sets a cookie and fetches from a cookie. I copied the code for JS and wrote the code for HTML , but I am unable to get the cookie. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) { // sets the cookie
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
     <!--user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");-->
     if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
     }
  }
}
</script>
<style>  // CSS details for login page creation .

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
}
#container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 395px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 30%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: -200x;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);

}
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
label {
    color: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
p a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-right: 20px;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
p a:hover {
    color: #555;
}
input {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #c7d0d2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    }
input[type=text]:hover,
input[type=password]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #b6bfc0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .7), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #a8c9e4;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #e6f2f9;
}
#lower {
    background: #ecf2f5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 69px;
    margin-top: 20px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.check {
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

input[type=submit] {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #acd6ef; /*IE fallback*/
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#acd6ef), to(#6ec2e8));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #66add6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b6e2ff), to(#6ec2e8));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
}

#imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.infosys {
  width: 50%;

}



</style>

</head>


<body>


    <form method = "post">
    <div id="container"> 
        <div id="imgcontainer">
            <img src="pic.png" alt="pic Logo" class="pic"  >
        </div>

        <br/>

            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" >
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <div id="lower">
                <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" onClick="checkCookie()">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I know if the username is stored successfully? Please do let me know , what mistake I'm doing and where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having 2 issues in your code. @camen6ert mentioned one of the issue and the second issue is that you are passing `user` variable to the `setCookie()` function which is empty and However, the cookie name should not be empty.

You need to replace your this part of your code:

```
if (user != "" && user != null) {
    setCookie("username", user, 30);
}
```

with this one:

```
if (user != "" || user != null) {
    setCookie("username", document.getElementById("username").value, 30);
}
```

Hope, it works for you.

Comment: I changed it Sahi Ahmed. Now how can I see if cookie is generated, I clicked on inpect--> applications--> cookie, there I am not finding anything, is the code still wrong ?

Comment: @Chandan I have tested the code and it works fine for me. It is showing username on Inspect -> Application -> Cookies -> Site URL.

Comment: @Chandan Here is the fiddle URL to verify this.
https://jsfiddle.net/sasiddiqui/d5kybrgh/

Comment: @Chandan You are closing the `</form>` at the wrong place. It should come after the `</div>` element in your code. Just for your reference. It doesn't affect the JS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of issues here that I will try to address:

- `<!-- -->` is an HTML comment - this is *not* how you comment out JS code, and results in a fatal syntax error. so `<!--user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");-->` should be `// user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");` if you want to comment out that line.

  - Since you commented out this line, the value of the variable user never gets set, and the if statement that follows it never evaulates to true and executes, since the variable is indeed equal to "". Either uncomment this line, or see note at bottom about fetch username value.
- You are using "onClick" when you should be using "onclick" - it should be `<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="checkCookie()">`

If you are trying to grab the username value from the form and save it into the cookie, you need to add code to that. Like:

```
function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
    user = document.getElementById("username").value;
     if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
     }
  }
}
```

Furthermore, if you are trying to interact with a form before it is submitted, you are much better off attaching your function to the form's onsubmit event.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I did everything you said, but I am still not able to to see the cookie stored.

Comment: It is working just fine for me, unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do - if you hit submit twice in this demo, the first time to store the cookie, the second submit click will alert with the username just like your code wants - https://jsfiddle.net/joshuatz/5ube4L96/